# Ubuntu 14.04 menu bar issue

Tags: unity, nautilus

I choose option show the menus in the window's title bar.

It works probably if I run an app in normal way, mean click on icon to open., but when I open it in terminal with root permission, the menu bar is no longer in title bar, it's in "a new part" (I think so) under the title bar.

Gedit and more are the same.

[image]

Comment: Me too, never noticed before, the drop downs are displayed in the window title bar as opposed to the task bar when opening any GUI as root, maby a permissions issue eg root does not own this taskbar ?

Comment: That is not something you can fix, that happens no matter what your settings are. The (settings of) placing the menu in either the global way or in the title bar is something you bypass by running it with gksu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK This is really a non-answer but there is too much information for a comment and iut may be the only answer.

First here is a bug report for this 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/894348

However there is no fix

Heres some info I found [Why don't applications opened as root use global menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40482/why-dont-applications-opened-as-root-use-global-menu)

For an application to use the global menu the environment variable $UBUNTU_MENUPROXY needs to be set to to the name of the menuproxy library to be used. For security reasons this variable is cleared when using sudo etc. to run a program as root.

As a side effect this indicates which programs are run as root, otherwise it may be not always clear that the items in the global menu belong to a program running as root.

As this are good reasons for the current behaviour I don't expect it to be changed.

This is really all I could find on this, to give a short answer

There is no fix this seems to be related to security in Ubuntu and root, there will probably never be a fix.

However if it really annoys you, you can remove the global menu (task bare menues) and put them on the windows for all users, like this

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

And put it back like this

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu
```

If you just want to remove it for the certain apps please review this http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/unity-global-menu-can-now-be-disabled.html

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: What did not work ? You must reboot to remove the menu